# Disable inertia for scroll iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, scroll, scrolltop

How is it possible to make in iPad safari browser stop scrolling after you release your finger? Ie.e to scroll without inertia?

I tried to find solution in jQuery but did not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery scoll addons. There are many plugins (e.G. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller etc...) in www.  Just google for "jQuery scrollbar plugin"...

Good luck

Comment: in fact it is what i looked for - but i cannot attach it for all document - i mean for body in css.. and in examples they attach it just for class or id..

Comment: Try http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/ .
This you use for "html" tag. Its my favorite. I used it 2 times now without any problems.

Good luck again